# Unpacking tuple in Python 2.7

Tags: python, tuples, args, keyword-argument

Actually working on a project where the homemade local DB api return all the result of SQL requests in tuples.

Like that :

```
result = ( (result1.1, result1.2... ), (result2.1, .... ) .... )
```

The problem is : when they unpack the tuple, we get many, many... ( many ) ValueErrors, because they do it like that :

```
( (result1.1, result1.2... ), (result2.1, .... ) .... ) = result
```

Which leads to these errors :

```
a = (1, 2)
(b,) = a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack

(b, c, d) = a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

What would be the best way to avoid these errors ( mostly due to the fact that we systematically add columns in the requests ) ?

I'm not really familiar with the *args **kwargs syntax, but I suppose we could use it?

Should we use another data structure (list, dictionary, ...)?

Edit :

```
def myFunction():

    sql = "SELECT a, b FROM myTable WHERE ...."
    myTuple = db.fetch(sql)        
    # I.E. : myTuple = ((a1, b1), (a2, b2))
    return myTuple

myTuple = myFunction()
for t in myTuple:
    (a, b) = t
```

My problem is : When I need to fetch column c in my request, how do I handle it when I unpack it?

Comment: That isn't currently valid Python, could you give a [mcve] of the data and the code that's processing it? Could you do e.g. `for result_tuple in result`? What happens next?

Comment: Who is `we` and who is `they`?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?  Tuple unpacking as an additional feature on python 3.

Comment: Any better? "We" are Me and the newer people to the project, "They" are the founders of the project

Comment: What database are you using? You can fetch dict or named tuple instead of tuple: [SQLite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory), [PostgreSQL](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.NamedTupleCursor)

Comment: I'm using postgres. 
Are you talking about :
from collections import namedtuple ?
I actually didn't know that one, seems answering the problem =D

Comment: "Are you talking about : from collections import namedtuple ?" - Yes. See example in psycopg documentation.

Comment: @AndreyT : You can answer that if you want me to accept it, cause even if I'm not using psycopg, the object namedtuple is very convenient.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use Better Data Structure

You should consider to use proper data like list of Classes / Objects then you don't need to "unpack" them like this

2. Play with data Part 1

```py
for subValue in a:
    my = GetValueOrDefault(subValue, 0)
    killer = GetValueOrDefault(subValue, 1)
    data = GetValueOrDefault(subValue, 2)

def GetValueOrDefault(value, index, default=None):
    returnValue = default

    try:
        returnValue = value[index]
    except:
        pass

    return returnValue
```

3. Play with data Part 2

```py
newDict = [{index: value for index, value in enumerate(item)} for item in result]
```

python is flexible, use what fits to your need

Comment: Camle-case in function names is violation of PEP-8!

Comment: Haha i know but you will find libraries which will use it! I am big fan of PEP-8 but as often in this world there are rules making Sense and rules they are not.

Comment: My eyes begin to bleed each time I see such function names in libraries :)

Comment: Then i hope you will not run out of blood some day,... NOT :)

Comment: Solution 1 looks like what AndreyT suggest me in the comments
Solution 2 seems very long to write, even if yes, it answers the problem
I already tried solution 3 which was the best option for me before knowing the existence of namedtuple

Answer (score 3):

For Python3: use asterisk syntax

```
result = ((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))
a, *_ = result
# a == (1,2)
# _ == [(3,4),(5,6)]
```

For Python2: use slices

```
result = ((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))
a, b = result[:2]
# a == (1,2)
# b == (3,4)
```

Comment: That's a solution I came across, even if slicing every single tuple makes me unconfortable